# Is it possible to create Infopath Colour schemes?

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

Infopath by default has a set of color schemes, I am wondering if it is possible to add my own color schemes to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible in IP 2007. Hopefully 2010 will change that but I haven't checked it out yet.

A possible workaround is to extract the form files and manually modify the CSS for the color scheme. Slightly more work than simply choosing a scheme from the picker but not entirely unfeasible.

Greg Collins, one of the MS Infopath MVPs, suggested this [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/infopath/Jun2005/post23313250.asp) and wrote up specific instructions in a post [here](http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/greg/archive/2005/06/07/Add-a-Custom-Style-Sheet-to-a-View.aspx).

Comment: I kind of figured that was the case. I had seen those articles by greg collins but as they were done in 2005 I was hoping that things might have changed.  Wishfull thinking I guess. thanks.